# What would be the best way in linux terminal to copy files to a bunch of subdirectories

Tags: linux, terminal

Here's the problem my teacher wants me to copy 3 files to over 10 different directories but instead of doing:
cp x1 x2 x3 ./dir1 then retyping it to copy those files to the next subdirectory.

But i was thinking what would be the best way to copy x1 x2 x3 using globbing to send them to multiple directories?

Comment: dont worry this is not for an exam or anything and the homework in question is already submitted, im just trying to see if there is a more efficient way of doing this

Comment: `using globbing` what globbing exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can do a bit of script a for cicle is good choiche:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    # ListOfDir
    ld=()

    # Add the right, full, path
    ld[0]=./dir1
    ld[1]=./dir2
    ld[2]=./dir3
    # ... Add the other dir

    # TODO : also the files can putted in an array...
    for curr_dir in ${ld[*]}; do cp x1 x2 x3 $curr_dir; done
```